# Calling action method in the controller from another action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a View, "Details", in which I am using `@Html.Begin.Form("Method1", "Controller1", FormMethod.Post)`. When clicking the submit, the `Method1` Action is called.

From `Method1`, I need to call another Action in the same Controller, called `Method2`, with an input parameter. Both `Method1` and `Method2` return `ActionResult`.

Every time I call `Method2`, either by using

```
Redirect.ToAction("Method2", "Controller1", new {parameter});
```

or

```
Redirect.ToAction(("Method2", new {parameter});
```

the parameter becomes null and an error pops up saying "no view supports the searched location or master was not found".

Also, `Method2` is `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: You cannot redirect to a POST method

Answer (score 0):

`Redirect.ToAction` sends `Get` request since your action is `HttpPost` so it does not finds the `action` but you can try this

```
return Method2(1,"parameter2");
```

suppose your `Method2` is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method2 (int someValue, string anotherValue) {
   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the Action `Method2` from `Method1` with parameters:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method2()
{
    ViewData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("param2", "param2Value"));
    ViewData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("param2", "param2Value"));
    return View();
}
```

And use this parameter in your view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    string param1  = Convert.ToString(ViewData["param1"]);
    string param2  = Convert.ToString(ViewData["param2"]);
}

<script> </script>

Html code here....
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. I used the below code to resolve it

```
Redirect.ToAction("Method2","Controller1", new {param = parameter});
```